# incremental value in query ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am making a query that shows values grouped by month, their count and their value like this:

```
Month  count  value
1       7      480€
2       8      500€
3       3      250€
```

and I want it to contain an incremental value like this:

```
Month  count  value  incr.  incr. val
1       7      480€   7       480€
2       8      500€   15      980€
3       3      250€   18      1230€
```

I can't do this at all.
I just can't or there is a way?

Comment: Please provide what that you have tried to write so far, because at this point looks like request for someone to do your job without you even attempting to solve it.

Comment: well first of all i tried to do it myself but what i wrote cleary wasn't right, so i googled it and i only found people who wanted an auto-increment field in the query, i searched deeper and i found a tech republic article that seemd okay but i couldn't get it to work, i tried looking again but i found nothing similar, i am working on this query from 4 hours ago and it's really complicated so vene if i wanted someone to do the job for me, this would be about the 1%

Comment: You don't need to provide code that works but code that you have tried to write, in many cases there is just one or two little things to change in your code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A funning value is a bit of a pain in MS Access, but you can calculate it using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.count)
        from t as t2
        where t2.month <= t.month
       ) as running_count,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from t as t2
        where t2.month <= t.month
       ) as running_value
from t;
```

Comment: `t` is table? so what is `t2` ?

Comment: @c.bene . . . It is a table alias.  The question doesn't mention a table name, so I just use `t` in my answers; it's easy to type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select t.*, (select sum(t1.count)
             from table t1
             where t1.Month <= t.Month  
            ) as incr,
            (select sum(t1.value)
             from table t1
             where t1.Month <= t.Month  
            ) as incrval,
from table t;
```